# owin active directory token validation random slowness and error

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, owin

I am facing some random authorisation problem when using following code to authenticate against ad active directory (I have a web api).

I believe this code will send a validation request to our azure active directory, but randomly we got validation error and some times it can take a while to get validation result back.

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = Constants.AzureActiveDirectoryTenant,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        // These values will be checked against what is received in the access token.
                        ValidAudiences = Constants.AzureActiveDirectoryValidAudiences
                    }
                });
```

Is it possible to understand why validation failed? Also about the speed, is it possible to create some custom method to cache a token on my web site? So I don't need to validate every request to AD all the time.

Comment: Could there be a connection string mismatch causing the requests to bounce around? Also, try a remote debug.

Comment: is there a log to see the reason for an authentication failure? I assume the token expired. But wants to see the log to confirm. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics nuget package](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/wiki/Debugging) to check the logs.

Alternatively, for a remote debug:

In Cloud Explorer in visual studio, find you web app and select "Remote Debugging."

Then publish your site in Debug mode.

In the portal, enable it by going to Application settings > Debugging > Remote Debugging > On